# mongodb aggregation query by using php

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

i have mongodb with database name travel and collection name sample with data as below

```
`{
    "_id": { id": "2344" },
    "places": { "destination": [ "singapore", "delhi" ] },
    "dt": { "date": "1434467400" }
},
{
    "_id": { id": "2345" },
    "places": { "destination": [ "singapore", "delhi" ] },
    "dt": { "date": "1434467445" }
},
{
    "_id": { "id": "2354" },
    "places": { "code": "7856", "source": [ "beijing", "singapore" ], "destination": [ "newyork", "landon", "sidney" ] },
    "dt": { "date": "1434589338" }
}`
```

i wrote monogdb aggregate function to find count of places

```
`db.sample.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$places", count : {$sum : 1}}}, {$sort: {count: 1}}])`
```

which shows result as

```
  { "_id" : { "destination" : [ "singapore", "delhi" ] }, "count" : 2 } \
  { "_id" : { "code" : "7856", "source" : [ "beijing", "singapore" ], "destination
" : [ "newyork", "landon", "sidney" ] }, "count" : 1 }
```

which gives count for each places by grouping places.

i have below these 2 requirements

1. i want to write this query in php with mongodb connection
2. if possible i want to get count based on code or source or destination which are inside places.

thanx in advance for help..

Comment: Hi Surendra, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm sorry to have to say this, but your question isn't really appropriate for this site. If you don't know at all how to code php which queries mongodb, then you need to find a suitable tutorial or course. You can come back to Stack Overflow if you are doing your coding and have a specific problem which you need help with, and can show the code which isn't working properly. Take a look at [ask] for some guidance.

Comment: Hi VinceBowdren, thanx for your suggestion. will try my best to come back with proper questions.